# Java DocumentDB connectivity without registering for Azure

Tags: java, azure, azure-cosmosdb

Is there a way to check java to documentDB connectivity without having to register on Azure? It will be great help even in case I can connect and select some data.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to be an Azure subscription owner/admin to use DocumentDB, but you still need a DocumentDB database account in Azure (there's no database you can install locally). You can then grab the SDK [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-java) and connect with code similar to:

```java
    DocumentClient documentClient = new DocumentClient(
       DOCDB_ENDPOINT,
       DOCDB_ACCESS_KEY,
       ConnectionPolicy.GetDefault(),
       ConsistencyLevel.Session);
```

From there, you can programmatically create databases and collections, and execute various CRUD operations.